# List of most recent questions

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to browse the list of questions asked, in reverse chronological order? The complete list of questions seems to sort it on number of votes and views. Wouldn't it be a nice option to have, if there is option at present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want -- https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest.

The questions in the list are sorted with the latest question on the top.

Comment: Was I blind or did you add it right now? ;-) That was stupid of me.